# A society where you imprison/ bury the females

Tags: society, creature-design, evolution

The hornbill imprisons its mate in a tree to deter predators. In Wayne Barlowe's Expedition, the sac-back female buries itself. What if something like this were a feature in a sentient species? How would that society work? What features could you see them having?

Comment: Like the Taleban? Or Wahabites in Persian Gulf?

Comment: Don't make this political

Comment: Your question is kinda political, and as much as what he said is probably a joke, he is right.

Comment: "Intelligent species" is pretty broad. For solely societal reasons it's unlikely this would hold stable. If that species had sexual dimorphism to a degree that neccessitates such structures, it might work, but that kind of leaves too much of the content creation to the answerer.

Comment: You mean forced prostitution?

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dying_of_the_Light_(1977_novel)

Comment: For one take on this, you can read the short story *The Monsters* by Robery Sheckley. It's about a society of aliens who (in a bit of a reversal) are visited by humans. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it for free online (some of Sheckley's other works are on Project Gutenberg), so you may need to find an actual publication or - e-book or physical. [Here is the ISFDB entry](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58569) to help track it down, if interested. I've not gone through all entries - some of the publications might be online. It might not be *exactly* what you ask but it's close.

Answer (score 2):

**How would it work?** *It wouldn't*

Simply speaking adding arbitrary restrictions to 50% of your population won't improve anything. Forcing people to not contribute politically, militarily, scientifically, or in the labor pool has never helped a country when giving the option to help can be allowed. In the best case scenario you get Roman/Victorian era ideas about the cult of domesticity, where the husband provides while the wife keeps the house. In the worst case scenario you get stuff like Wahabites in Persian Gulf who keep women in restrictive and/or oppressive clothing that buries women from view. This society would likely be very oppressive to women, since women have more trouble voicing their opinions.

Look up any old societies that kept women essentially under house arrest or place in the middle east where sharia and other law keep most women in that condition also.

Comment: Assuming the sentient species is human-like. What if it's something like ants/bees. And the species female is a hive queen that just produces new members of the hive and naturally hidden and protected. And too busy to do anything else.

Comment: In that case, it would be a matriarchy. The queen would either have full control of the society, or once democracy comes about, would serve as a queen in the same way that the English queen does.

Comment: Not necessary. Notion that the hive queen has absolute control over the hive is false even for earthly insects. For example the specie can have a female and male members only for procreation, and they can even be unintelligent; while majority of genderless individuals that do all the work in the hive possess sentience. And they hide&protect the "queen" only because it's the only source of new members of their society.

Comment: Like how honey bees bite the head off of their queen when she stops producing enough eggs to make way for a new more fertile queen?